# insert JSON array data in database table

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, sqlite

I've searched all around the web for a similar question as what i want but i couldn't find any. 
So, I made an app where i get news data from JSON and display it in a list, it's all good, but now i want to add something to it, when there is no internet connection i want to display the latest list viewed. to do this i thought of storing the JSON arraylist in a databases and update it whenever the news change while there's a connection so when there's no connection it'll display the data in the database. 
the thing is I'm kind of lost on how to do this..

I made a java class called NewsDBHelper where i create my database and table.

```
public class NewsDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String LOG_TAG = NewsDBHelper.class.getSimpleName();

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "news.db";

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public NewsDBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String SQL_CREATE_PRODUCTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + Contract.NewsEntry.TABLE_NAME + " ("
            + Contract.NewsEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + Contract.NewsEntry.COLUMN_SECTION + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + Contract.NewsEntry.COLUMN_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL,  "
            + Contract.NewsEntry.COLUMN_DATE + " BLOB, "
            + Contract.NewsEntry.COLUMN_AUTHOR + " TEXT DEFAULT NULL, "
            + Contract.NewsEntry.COLUMN_URL + " BLOB);";

    Log.v(LOG_TAG,SQL_CREATE_PRODUCTS_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_PRODUCTS_TABLE);
}
```

Then in my mind the idea is when the JSON data are stored in an array, i'd take the array values and store them in the table.

```
private static List<News> extractFeatureFromJson(String newsJSON) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newsJSON)) {
        return null;
    }

    List<News> news = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(newsJSON);
        String response = baseJsonResponse.getString("response");
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
        ;
        JSONArray newsArray = object.getJSONArray("results");
        for (int i = 0; i < newsArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject currentNews = newsArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String title = currentNews.getString("webTitle");
            String section = currentNews.getString("sectionName");
            String date = currentNews.getString("webPublicationDate");
            JSONArray tag = currentNews.getJSONArray("tags");
            String author = null;
            if (tag.length() != 0) {
                author = tag.getJSONObject(0).getString("firstName");
            }
            String url = currentNews.getString("webUrl");

            News nNews = new News(title, date, section, author, url);

            news.add(nNews);

            //add news array in the table
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("QueryUtils", "Problem parsing the news JSON results", e);
    }
    return news;
}
```

i don't really know how to do this or if it's possible even. if it is how can i do it? or what's the best way to implement my idea?

Answer (score 0):

you're are 70% done with what you're trying to do.

All you need to do now is:

- Get a writable database from the NewsDBHelper
- Create a content values of the data you want to insert to db
- Call the insert() method on the writable database, passing it the content values.
- And fetching the persisted data from the database at due time.

Below is a sample code that adopts the above listed steps.

```
//Create an instance of NewsDBHelper
NewsDBHelper newsDBHelper = new NewsDBHelper(context);

//get a writable database from newsDBHelper 
SQLiteDatabase writableDatabase = newsDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

//create content values of data to persist 
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("section","Sample section");
values.put("title","Sample title");
values.put("date","1/29/2018");
values.put("author","John Chan");
values.put("url","https://example.com");

//write the data to the database. Notice that the "news" is the table name  
writableDatabase.insert("news",null,values);
```

To fetch data from the database, get a readable database from the newsDBHelper like this:

```
SQLiteDatabase readableDatabase = newsDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();

//query or read data from the database by calling:
readableDatabase.query(String table, String[] columns, String selection, 
String[] selectionArgs,String groupBy, String having, 
String orderBy, String limit);
```

For more information on SQLiteOpenHelper, Readable, and Writable Databases, check out the official the documentation of [SQLiteDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)

Comment: but that's not what i want. i wan't to save the data from json to the database

Comment: I understand your question, but you'll have to iterate the list of new,  create content value for every individual news and persist in database using the above method.